# How to launch fragment from FirebaseMessagingService class in java

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to launch fragment from FirebaseMessagingService class in Android Studio.

Comment: Am looking for the answer. Did you manage to figure out?